# How to set value of input type text from a Directive, that takes a random value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wrote the following function to set the value of input type="text". The value is a randomly picked array element.

```
(function func(){
    var qArray = ['This','is','a','test','string','that','has'];
    for(var i =0;i<qArray.length;i++) {
            var que = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
            console.log(qArray[que]);
        }
        document.getElementById("q").setAttribute("value", qArray[que]);
        document.getElementById("q").innerHTML = qArray[que];

    })()
```

http://jsbin.com/daturahu/1/    //working

Now my rest of the code is in AngularJs and it is difficult for me to update the input type = "text" value with the array element using angualrjs. I know I have to create a directive and play around with it but I can't get it to work. Can someone take a look and please help;

My jsbin is here,

http://jsbin.com/xelerusu/1/   //broken

Comment: why do you want to set value attribute? will you use it in jquery function?

Comment: I need a function to execute that takes as parameter the value of textbox.

Comment: why don't you just bind it to ng-model and give ng-click to to button which trigger a function on controller??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you esspecially look to `value` attribute of `input`, if this is the case just change your template to this...

```
template:'<input type="text" id="q" value="{{val}}">'
```

and in the link function of directive set $scope.val as you want

```
link: function(scope, element, attr){
  var qArray = ['This','is','a','test','string','that','has'];
  for(var i =0;i<qArray.length;i++) {
    var que = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
  }
  scope.val = qArray[que];
}
```

here is [JSBIN EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/xelerusu/6)...

Answer (score 1):

As my understanding, you just need to put all your function to `link` property of your `directive`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('myAppdirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<input type="text" id="q">',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            var qArray = ['This','is','a','test','string','that','has'];
            for(var i =0;i<qArray.length;i++) {
                var que = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
                console.log(qArray[que]);
            }
            element.val(qArray[que]);
        }
    }
})
```

http://jsbin.com/xelerusu/3

Comment: Thanks Iqbal. but if you look at the DOM, in inspect element there isn't any value set for the input type?

Comment: This is because you set its value using javascript. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Yaniv: I have a button next to input type that on clicking should give me the value of input box

Comment: ok - you can read the input value using element.val() (although you won't see the value via inspector: http://jsbin.com/xelerusu/7/edit)